Fundamental reasons for using vapors for ALD rather than solutions
Atomic layer deposition (ALD) has been developed for many materials, as can be seen from this overview: https://atomiclimits.com/alddatabase/
However, a search for liquid phase ALD gives less results.
I know, one reason may be that solvent molecules protect the substrate surface from reactants.

Is this the only reason why mostly vapor phase is preferred?
Why is it not possible to pick solvents which bind weakly enough to the surface to enable ligand exchange?
Do you know any examples of exceptions (where liquid phase is advantageous for some purpose)?
Am I missing the key terminology for searching? The related synonyms can be misleading.


IMHO, for ALD, you want rather slow, diffusion driven process than fast, adsorption driven process.

No solvent is as inert as vacuum.

BTW you seem to be overenthusiastic with bounties. There are other ways of promoting questions. You can try chat for example.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_bath_deposition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dip-coating https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wetting_layer

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-space_sublimation

@Mithoron Wikipedia gives no example for the statement "Self-assembly can give film thicknesses of exactly one mono layer" in the dip-coating article.

@Mithoron Chemical bath deposition is mostly not for monolayer deposition. My question was basically "Why not?"


"No solvent is as inert as vacuum." On the other hand, salts can be recrystallized at lower temperatures with the help of a polar solvent than via sublimation through vacuum. I know, ALD is not a recrystallization, but it still needs volatile/soluble precursors. Lower temperature might be useful for some heat-sensitive substrate.


Key word is atomic, not many atoms in solution as atoms. Have you considered electroplating? The technique has been used to form monolayers on water.

@jimchmst I have considered electroplating. As far as I know, it only works for relatively smooth surfaces and not for freely floating particles.
